# What is this succulent? I can't find it on Google Lens

Tags: identification, succulents

I tried Google Lens and an app on my phone, still couldn't figure it out what it is.

sorry about the photo positions, I don't know why they don't position right.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like some species of Sedum (common name "stonecrop"). There are about 500 species so it's hard to tell exactly which one you have! If it flowers next year, that will make identification easier. They like bright light (direct sunlight is fine) and don't over-water them. Some species are frost tolerant, at least in UK conditions down to about -10C.

Comment: @alephzero Thanks! i looked into it and found Cremnosedum is very closed to what i have